# Get User ids by country name

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have following table structure.

```
<h1>ID Country</h1>
1      Country1 <br/>
2      Country2 <br/>
3      Country3 <br/>
4      Country1 <br/>
5      Country2 <br/>
6      Country3 <br/>
7      Country1 <br/>
8      Country2 <br/>
9      Country3 <br/>
10      Country1 <br/>
11      Country2 <br/>
12      Country3 <br/>
```

I need output based on country i pass to sql query

if i pass Country as Country1

then i should get output as following

```
1 Country1
4 Country1
2 Country2
5 Country2
7 Country1
10 Country1
3 Country3
6 Country3
```

In summary 2 country result

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your question is not clear,then post your code what you developed so far

Comment: Looks like you want the first and second id for each country but I don't get why you would pass country1

Comment: Sorry for mistake in sql result.
if i pass country1 outputs should be like this

1 Country1
4 Country1
2 Country2
5 Country2
7 Country1
10 Country1
3 Country3
6 Country3

Comment: What is the logic between sample data and expect result?

Comment: Logic in output data is country1 is repeating after countr2 repeat 2 times

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT uid, country
FROM table_name
ORDER BY country ASC;
```

(or DESC, what you need)

Comment: Or maybe
ORDER BY country, id 

Default will be ASC, so if you want DESC you can add it per column